# Beginner: Problem with formatting

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1.The sequence \{a_n\} verconges to a if for all \epsilon > 0
\end{document}^
```

Output:

> 1.The sequence {a n }vercongestoaifforall? > 0

I don't know what to do to remove the clumping after an.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is that `a_n` is something that should occur in math mode, as are `\epsilon` and `>`. In (La)TeX, `_` indicates a subscript but it can only be used in math mode (triggered with wither `$...$` or `\[...\]`). Similarly, `\epsilon` and `>` can only be used in math mode. So when the document is compiled, your errors are being fixed, and the compiler is doing its best to guess where you wanted math mode to start and where you wanted it to end, so it does `\{a$_n\} verconges to a if for all \epsilon >$0`.

Comment: Instead, you should do something like `\{$a_n$\} verconges to a if for all $\epsilon >$0.`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And thank you for the welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing math and text modes.  You need to bracket the mathematics correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

In-line math

1.The sequence \(\{a_n\}\) converges to \(a\) if for all \(\epsilon > 0\)

Display math

1.The sequence \[\{a_n\}\] converges to \[a\] if for all \[\epsilon > 0\]

\end{document}
```

You use `\(` and `\)` to bracket in-line mathematics and `\[` and `\]` for display mathematics

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Fixed, thanks, I proofed that too late last night.